# Sell one unique item with Woocommerce?

Tags: plugins

I would like to sell drawings and paintings using Woocommerce. Woocommerce is expecting that there are more copies of each product, but the problem is there is only one (1) of each drawing/painting.

How can I create in Woocommerce a unique product? So after this product is sold, processed and completed it is shown as 'sold out'.

Can this be solved with a piece of code? Or does anyone know about a plugin? I wasn’t able to find anything.

Please help an artist!

Comment: Sorry, but you'll have to do some research and try to solve it yourself first. Plugin recommendations are off topic and if you ain't know a bit how to wrangle with code, you'll have to get someone for a professional "hands on".

Comment: @kaiser My apologies. I certainly do not want to beg for a plugin. I have been searching for about 6 hours last night. So i guess that would have been research enough. I think i have seen each and any plugin and snippet for WC available. I do was hoping for a reply made by Sarah, because that seems to be the solution.

Comment: _"Or does anyone know about a plugin?"_ is the critical line. See the close message and read a bit in the [help] to get more info about how to ask questions that won't get closed :) Btw, please only mark a solution as solution if it _really works_, not if it seems so.

Comment: pity this is closed it's an important answer anyway if not question - I'm sure there's a decent reason plugin recommendations are off topic - but in reality, they're just as important ( to me anyway ) as pieces of code

Answer (score 11):

This should be possible with the built-in features of WordPress.   In your WooCommerce Settings, in the Inventory tab, enable Stock Management.  Then, when you create or edit a product, select the Inventory tab in the Product Data section and enable stock management for that product.  You will then be able to set a stock quantity of 1 (and make sure that backorders aren't allowed).

Once that 1 item has been sold, WooCommerce will automatically change the status to say 'Out of stock' and will not allow that product to be sold again.

For a situation like this, you may also want to customise the messages displayed to the user to something other than the default 'Out of stock'/'1 in stock'.   To change it to show Sold/Available instead, you can use the `woocommerce_stock_html` filter.   Just add code like the following to your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_html', 'change_stock_message', 10, 2);
function change_stock_message($message, $stock_status) {
    if ($stock_status == "Out of stock") {
        $message = '<p class="stock out-of-stock">Sold</p>';    
    } else {
        $message = '<p class="stock in-stock">Available</p>';           
    }
    return $message;
}
```

Comment: I feel stupid... I would have never expected that if i don't want to use Stock, i actually have to enable Stock Management. But that did the trick indeed.
And the code works like a charm!

Comment: Tested and code continues to work in 2020 with WordPress 5.5.1

Comment: What if i want the item to disappear from the store, it's unique and has been sold, it shouldn't be in the store anymore.